# R: how to filter out rows that end with a specific list characters?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
+-----------------+--------+
| Geography       | Values |
+-----------------+--------+
| Atlanta, GA     | 78     |
+-----------------+--------+
| New York, NY    | 30     |
+-----------------+--------+
| Denver, CO      | 20     |
+-----------------+--------+
| Omaha, NE       | 178    |
+-----------------+--------+
| Los Angeles, CA | 58     |
+-----------------+--------+
| Providence, RI  | 100    |
+-----------------+--------+
| Little Rock, AR | 20     |
+-----------------+--------+
| Miami, FL       | 50     |
+-----------------+--------+
| ...             |        |
+-----------------+--------+
```

I would look to perform an operation in tidyverse/dplyr format so that I can **filter out any rows that is from the state of GA & CA**. Notice that there is always a ", " (a comma, followed by a space) before the state abbreviation.

The resulting dataframe should look like:

```
+-----------------+--------+
| Geography       | Values |
+-----------------+--------+
| New York, NY    | 30     |
+-----------------+--------+
| Denver, CO      | 20     |
+-----------------+--------+
| Omaha, NE       | 178    |
+-----------------+--------+
| Providence, RI  | 100    |
+-----------------+--------+
| Little Rock, AR | 20     |
+-----------------+--------+
| Miami, FL       | 50     |
+-----------------+--------+
| ...             |        |
+-----------------+--------+
```

The real data is much larger than this simple example. It is consists of hundreds of cities with multiple cities in a state, so I can not simply do something like:

```
data %>%
filter (Geography == "Atlanta, GA" | Geography == "Los Angeles, CA")
```

Should I create a new "State" column that takes out the last 2 letters of the "Geography" column, and filter on that "State" column, or can I do something regex related such as:

```
exclude_list = c("GA, CA")

data %>%
filter (Geography != end_with(exclude_list))
```

What is an elegant way to do this? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can construct `exclude_list` as :

```
exclude_list = c("GA", "CA")
```

Then use `subset` as :

```
subset(data, !grepl(sprintf('(%s)$', 
                    paste0(exclude_list, collapse = '|')), Geography))
```

Or if you need `dplyr` answer do :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  filter(!grepl(sprintf('(%s)$', 
                paste0(exclude_list, collapse = '|')), Geography))
```

where

```
sprintf('(%s)$', paste0(exclude_list, collapse = '|')) #returns
#[1] "(GA|CA)$"
```

---

If `exclude_list` is too big the regex answer might fail in such case suggestion by @thelatemail would be helpful where we keep only the state name and match them with `%in%` :

```
data[!sub("^.+,\\s+", "", data$Geography) %in% exclude_list,]
```

Comment: The more I think about these cases, I'm not convinced making a giant regex is a good scalable solution when you can do something like `dat[!sub("^.+,\\s+", "", dat$Geography) %in% exclude_list,]` which won't fall over or slow down dramatically if `exclude_list` gets too big.

Comment: Hmm...that's true. I added an update to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this with regex. The `$` in a regular expression indicates the end of the line. So `grepl(" CA$", Geography)` will return true if the geography ends with a space and the letters CA.

Hence I would do something like:

```r
data %>%
  filter(!grepl(" CA$", Geography),
         !grepl(" GA$", Geography))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option with `grepl`

```
> setDT(df)[!grepl(",\\s+(CA|GA)$", Geography)]
         Geography Values
1:    New York, NY     30
2:      Denver, CO     20
3:       Omaha, NE    178
4:  Providence, RI    100
5: Little Rock, AR     20
6:       Miami, FL     50
```

or `subset` if you are with base R

```
> subset(df, !grepl(",\\s+(CA|GA)$", Geography))
        Geography Values
2    New York, NY     30
3      Denver, CO     20
4       Omaha, NE    178
6  Providence, RI    100
7 Little Rock, AR     20
8       Miami, FL     50
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Geography = c("Atlanta, GA", "New York, NY", "Denver, CO", 
"Omaha, NE", "Los Angeles, CA", "Providence, RI", "Little Rock, AR",
"Miami, FL"), Values = c(78L, 30L, 20L, 178L, 58L, 100L, 20L,
50L)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-8L))
```